# Question about questions on topics

Tags: discussion

If I have a question related to an already asked question, but I want clarification, how should I go about asking this? Should I make a new question?

Thank you

Comment: Related: [Clarify an old answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4108/clarify-an-old-answer)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Clarification: Yes, ask a new question. Yes, put a link to the old one in your question. Yes, explain what you don't understand and want clarified.